# How to implement multiple language site in laravel

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any package of laravel 5.2 for creating site in multiple language.
Can any one suggest for such implementation.

Comment: Laravel do have that build in, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy and simply done by follow a few steps to create multi language site with laravel 5.2:

- Create `locales`
- Use prefix for routes
- Handle middleware for multi-language support

You can read more about steps with package [Laravel Localization](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/mcamara/laravel-localization).